# Laravel Session driver memcached not working

Tags: php, laravel, memcached

I am trying to set up Laravel to use memcached as a session driver, but I can't get it to work.

- I have installed memcached on my Windows development machine
- It works in the "regular" cache configuration

I get no error whatsoever in the Laravel log.

I have no idea what could be wrong, and there's little on setting memcached as a session driver for Laravel, or at least little on the problem I am experiencing.

I am using PHP 5.5 and Laravel 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in Laravel config/cache.php uses Memcache (without the -d) and config/session.php uses Memcached (with the -d). Unfortunately, as far as I found out, MemcacheD isn't available for Windows platforms (or at least the PHP version I'm using).

Comment: check this (https://laravel.io/index.php/forum/05-25-2014-laravel-memcached-on-wamp).